# Does a language dictate the order of the word?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Lets take the Language $$L = \{ (ab)^na^k | n \ge k \}$$

Does it dictate, that the $(ab)^n$ comes before the $a^k$ ? Or is the order irrelevant as long as it matches the $n \ge k$ criterium?

In simple terms: is the word $aaaababab \in L$ ?

And if so, does this apply for every language?

Comment: Yes, order matters. The fundamental operation is "string concatenation", for which order is important. One question: if you were happy about transposing $(ab)^n$ and $a^k$, why wouldn't you also be happy about transposing the $a$ and $b$ inside $(ab)^n$ to get a string like $aaabbabb$?

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. I've a problem trying to show that I'm able to pump up $a^k$ (pumping-lemma)... but that's one for another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, order matters. The fundamental operation used in the definition of language $L$ is "string concatenation", for which order is important.

One question: if you were happy about transposing $(ab)^n$ and $a^k$, why wouldn't you also be happy about transposing the $a$ and $b$ inside $(ab)^n$ to get a string like $aaabbabb$?

Of course it's possible to construct languages which are stable under "anagraming", but you'll need to make that explicit in the notation, for instance:

$$L_2 = \left\{ w \in \{a,b\}^*  \, \middle| \, \#_a(w) \geq \#_b(w) \right\}$$

now $L_2$ is the language of all words that contain more $a$ than $b$, regardless of order.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped me a lot!

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi I agree. But the language $L$ in the question is defined by the concatenation notation used in $(ab)^na^k$, and that is why two words $w_1$ and $w_2$ can be anagrams of eachother even though $w_1 \in L$ and $w_2 \notin L$. The language $L_2$ in my answer also consists of words which are ordered sequences of letters by definition, yet $L_2$ is agnostic of the order of letters in its words, because it doesn't use concatenation in its definition.

Comment: Words are ordered by definition, even before introducing concatenation. First we define words, then we define concatenation.

Comment: @Stef You can look at any word as a concatenation of letters, this does not make it the reason for "order matters". Order matters because words are ordered sequences of letters.

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi Sorry, I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: For us to able to define concatenation, we need to have words defined first. Words are defined as ordered sequences of letters already.

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi Yes? I don't disagree with the fact that words are words. I just don't understand your point.

Comment: The point is that order matters because words are ordered by definition, not because order matters in concatenation. Its a note that the order comes from words, and then concatenation was defined without ruining it.

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi I still have no idea what you're trying to get at. "Order matters in language L" because concatenation operation is used in the definition of language L. "Order doesn't matter in language L2" because the only operations used in the definition of language L2 are $\#_a$ and $\#_b$, which don't care about order of letters in words.

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi "Order doesn't matter in language L2" means that for all words w1 and w2 such that w2 is a permutation of w1, either both w1 and w2 in L2, or neither w1 nor w2 in L2. "Order matters in L1" means there exist w1 and w2 which are permutations of eachother and such that w1 in L1 and w2 not in L2.

Comment: Your answer is fine. I just did not like the way it is written. It confuses words with concatenation of letters. At the end of the day, it does not matter as everything is consistent, but to be precise, note that $ab$ is a word and $a\cdot b$ is a concatenation of two words. Before even defining concatenation, the word $ab$ does not equal the word $ba$ as words are ordered -- that's the origin of it. Anyway, people do not make the distinction between $ab$ and $a\cdot b$, its just a side note.

Comment: @BaderAbuRadi I'm a bit unhappy about the way I wrote it too. After your first comment I edited to replace "The fundamental operation" with "The fundamental operation used in the definition of language L". If you have other suggestions they are welcome.

Comment: I think the following serves as an answer: "order matters because words are defined as ordered sequences of letters. For example, the words $ab$ and $ba$ are different". Anyway, sorry for the annoying discussion in the comment section.